# How to import chilikat classes to swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use chilikat's ftp classes in my project. But when I tried to compile I got an error(shown below) from xcode. What reason of that error?
And my second question is: I used this import statement:`#import "CkoFtp2/CkoFtp2.h"` and I got the second error here?

Path of bridging header file:

[image]

P.S. I got the path by dragging the file into terminal.

Comment: try #import <CkoFtp2/CkoFtp2.h>

Comment: Unfortunately same errors @Shoaib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that the problem is in the path of the bridging header. That path is fine (otherwise you wouldn't have gotten an error about the `#import` line inside the bridging header).

The problem appears to be the `CkoFtp2/CkoFtp2.h` header path. Looking at your directory listing, there is no `CkoFtp2` subdirectory, but rather you appear to have copied it to your main project directory. That means that you should try:

```
#import "CkoFtp2.h"
```

Comment: I got 380 errors with that. But this time errors coming from CkoFtp2.h file. These are like syntax errors unlike linking errors.

Comment: I solved with adding Foundation Framework to chilicat files. Thanks